# Editing Batch through VB.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, compiler-construction, richtextbox

I am currently building a transcompiler for batch and I want an option where you can edit existing batch files through a Rich Textbox in VB.Net How does one do this? It is known knowledge that you can edit batch files through notepad without even touching the file type.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you've even tried to find out because it's as simple as calling the `LoadFile` and `SaveFile` methods of the `RichTextBox`.  It's just a text file, regardless of the file extension, so you treat it like you do any other text file.

Comment: @jmcilhinney PRAISE THE LORD FOR THE SIMPLICITY OF CODING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StreamReader` to load the text into the `RichTextBox`. For example:

```
Dim StreamReader1 As New IO.StreamReader
RichTextBox1.Text = StreamReader1.ReadToEnd()
```

You may also want to use an `OpenFileDialog` to load the file. Add a `OpenFileDialog` to your `Form` first.

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Open a Batch File"
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Batch files (*.bat) | *.bat"
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
     Dim StreamReader1 As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
     RichTextBox1.Text = StreamReader1.ReadToEnd
     StreamReader1.Close()
Else
     'What to do if OpenFileDialog is cancelled
End If
```